# Install Applications on Windows RDP Servers with Puppet

Tags: puppet, remote-desktop-services

The scenario is installing Windows applications with Puppet on a Windows RDP server. I have Puppet install the applications without problem, but per the *best practice*, you're supposed to be in `install` mode when doing so, and switching back to `execute` mode.

I can do the following and it works:

```
package {'Adobe AIR':
  ensure          => '15.0.0.356',
  source          => '\\myserver\adobeair.exe',
  install_options => ['-silent', '-eulaAccepted'],
  require         => Exec['installmode'],
  before          => Exec['executemode'],
}

exec {'installmode':
  command => 'c:/Windows/System32/change.exe user /install',
}
exec {'executemode':
  command => 'c:/Windows/System32/change.exe user /execute',
}
```

What I'm trying to solve here is that everytime Puppet runs, it considers that something was done as the two `Exec` run each time regardless if the application really install or not.

I would like to silence the execution of `Exec`, or find a better way to switch between `install` and `execute` mode.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps it is something that can be added to package as an enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

I created [PUP-3979](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3979) for you.

This would need to run when a server is configured with Remote Desktop Services (whether executing install locally or from a remote session):

> To ensure that an application is installed correctly to work in a
>   multiuser environment, you must put the RD Session Host server into a
>   special installation mode before you install the application on the RD
>   Session Host server. This special installation mode ensures that the
>   correct registry entries and .ini files that are needed to support
>   running the application in a multiuser environment are created during
>   the installation process.

From TechNet: [Install Programs on an RD Session Host Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742815.aspx)

Comment: I'm guessing that is the use case where this would be necessary.

Comment: `change.exe` is to set the mode of the RDP server, whether your local admin or not. It triggers Windows to monitor for Registry changes that are not compatible with multi-user environment. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742815.aspx

Comment: @ETL Quite a bit of editing to my answer there - lost an important discussion point. Does this apply to the locally running services and users? Or not? Puppet agent normally runs as a local service so we're trying to figure out if this is a necessary change or not.

Comment: Nevermind, you commented on the ticket with that information. Which is YES, it doesn't matter if local or remote.